# Why am I getting the error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, es6-promise, amazon-textract

I have an index.js, gettext.js and extract.js.

***index.js***

```
app.post("/anaData", async function(req, res) {
  const someData = await docExtract(req.body['file_name'])
  const data = await getData(someData)
  .....
 ....
}
```

***gettext.js***

```
async function docExtract (file_name) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
     var file_params = {
       Document: {
         S3Object: {
           Bucket: bucket_name,
           Name: filename
         }
       },
       FeatureTypes: ['TABLES'],
     }
     
     textract.analyzeDocument(file_params, (err, data) => {
       if (err) {
         return resolve(err)
       } else {
         resolve(data)
       }
     })
   })
 }
 module.exports = docExtract
```

***extract.js***

```
async function getData(data) {
    const blocks = data['Blocks']
  
    const blocksMap = {}
    const tableBlocks = []
  
    blocks.forEach(block => {  //At this point the error is generated: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"
      blocksMap[block['Id']] = block
  ....
....
}
  module.exports = getData
```

I am sending the right json data. I have checked that req.body['file_name'] is accessible. The problem seems to be related to the fact that the docExtract function return a promise but I just can't seem to understand what do I do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error message reads:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at extract (path\to\getData.js:75:12)
    at path\to\index.js:28:22
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: The source of the error is `blocks` is undefined. So the `forEach` loop fails... And then, the promise also fails. Make sure `data['Blocks']` is defined in `getData()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Cannot read property 'forEach'...

The error is saying it's trying to read a property `forEach`. That means this expression:

```
blocks.forEach
```

> ...of undefined

...which means that `blocks` is undefined. That means when you assign the value:

```
const blocks = data['Blocks']
```

...`data['Blocks']` has the value `undefined`.

Because `getData` is an `async function`, it returns a `Promise`. If the function throws an error, and it does (trying to read `forEach` property of an `undefined` value), the promise becomes a rejection. "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" means that the caller of `getData` is not handling these rejections. If you wrap the `await` in a `try/catch`, you can catch any error that `getData` throws and do something useful with it, like sending an HTTP error response.

So hopefully this explains what the error '“UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined”' means.

So to avoid the error:

1. To avoid unhandled rejections, make sure when you call `getData()` or any other async function you await the result and catch errors. If you do not, then any errors, expected or unexpected, will be unhandled.
2. To avoid reading properties of undefined values, make sure the data you're accessing is actually in the format you're expecting. In this case, it looks like `data['Blocks']` is undefined, so you're either not getting the data you're expecting or you're accessing it incorrectly. Try logging `data` to see what you're actually getting. By the way, `data.Blocks` is equivalent and less typing than `data['Blocks']`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive explanation. I understand a lot about the error that it was throwing. I inherited the code from someone else and I don't understand why it doesn't have error handling anywhere. However, the mistake I was making was very silly. The bucket_name parameter is actually being taken from an environment file and I mistakenly put the environment variable name wrong by pasting it from another location.

Comment: Gotta love mistakes like that :D. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a js expert but in my experience, `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` in this case with `await` occur because `await` is the short version of promise handling, but only the `resolve` part.

i.e. If some exceptions are thrown inside the promise function or if the promise `reject`s, then `await` is not handling that.

My educated guess is that `textract.analyzeDocument()`'s callback `(err, data) => {}` part is simply rejecting it.

Comment: You were right, it was actually rejecting it because I was giving the wrong parameters to analyzeDocument(). Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very silly mistake that was leading to the error. The bucket_name variable was getting substituted from an environment variable and the variable name in gettext.js and environment file were different.